# log4j2 logs debug to file but empty if I switch to info

Tags: selenium, debugging, logging, log4j2

My info.log remains empty even though I'm getting logs written for the debug file...
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Console logs INFO normally

```
<Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
    </Console>

    <File name="DebugFile" fileName="logs/Debug.log" immediateFlush="false" append="true">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </File>

    <File name="InfoFile" fileName="logs/Info.log" immediateFlush="false" append="false">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </File>        
</Appenders>

<Loggers>
    <Root level="debug">
        <AppenderRef ref="Console" level="info"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="DebugFile" level="debug"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="InfoFile" level="info"/>
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```

Comment: I can't recreate your problem, but I think it could be immediateFlush="false" depending on when you're checking the content of the log.

Comment: @D.B. omg! having immediate flush actually did the trick! Could you explain why debug didnt require immediate flush but INFO did?

Comment: Having that attribute set to false means it won't necessarily write the data to the log file immediately. It has nothing to do with the log level, it has everything to do with the size of the buffer and how much data you're writing.

Comment: @D.B. I can it was because my debug data was so large it exceeded the buffer super quickly hence the immediate writing to the log file. Thanks for your answer!